# Prompt user for Query Parameter MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to have a user choose yes/no and add a parameter in a query based upon that answer?

I have a table that has a 'status' field. One of the statuses can be complete. There is a report that prints out that has this field. Sometimes I want the records that are marked as complete, and sometimes I do not.

Is it possible to prompt the user and ask if they want the completed records, using the criteria/expression builder in a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would be to use a yes-no msgbox to learn whether the criteria should be shown, then run the report using the "where" parameter on the DoCmd.OpenReport command.

```
Dim intAnswer As Integer

Dim intAnswer As Integer

intAnswer = MsgBox("Show the details?", vbYesNo)

If intAnswer = vbYes Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Form1", acViewPreview, , "[Status] <> ""Completed""", acWindowNormal, "Yadda Yadda"
Else
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Form1", acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal, "Zippity Doohdah"
End If
```

If you would like to inform the report of what the user selected one method is to pass an `OpenArgs` string and then have a label on the report that shows that string.  (Above I pass the phrase "Yadda Yadda", or "Zippity Dodah")

On the report, add a label (here called Label1) and set its Caption equal to the OpenArgs:

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)

   If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
       Me.Label1.Caption = Me.OpenArgs
   End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Is there a way to print a string on the report indicating which choice the user selected for example, if intAnswer = yes, then the report will say active contracts, and if they select no, the report will say all contracts?

Comment: That is to say, a text box or label or something with a string in it that represents in some way what the user clicked. Like a variable called "Choice" being set in either block and then the text object on the report displaying that variable.